# HY000 - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366

Tags: php, sql

This throws error "HY000 - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'likes + 1' for column 'likes' at row 1". What am i doing wrong? When it's executed without binding values, it works fine.

```
    public static function update($set, $where)
    {
        //$set = ["likes" => "likes + 1"];
        //$where = ["path" => "SomePath"];
        $tableName = static::tableName();
        $toSet = implode(", ", array_map(fn($attr) => "$attr = :$attr", array_keys($set)));
        $inWhere = implode(", ", array_map(fn($attr) => "$attr = :$attr", array_keys($where)));
        $statement = self::prepare("UPDATE $tableName SET $toSet WHERE $inWhere;");
        foreach ($set as $key => $value) {
            $statement->bindValue(":$key", $value);
        }
        foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
            $statement->bindValue(":$key", $value);
        }
        $statement->execute();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried displaying the SQL statement it's trying to run?

Comment: Yes. UPDATE articles SET likes = :likes WHERE path = :path;

Comment: So when you bind the value of `:likes`, it will bind `"likes + 1"` as a literal.